# What does the folder 'Modules' do in a React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module, architecture

I am analyzing the architecture of a React Native app, and while I can understand most of the ideas behind most of the folders, the folder modules eludes me.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to read the redux doc -- this is all resux stuff https://redux.js.org/

Comment: Thank, I'll give it a look, if you want to post that as the answer I can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These directories are used to support redux -- if you look at the redux documentation it should explain how to use redux modules.  at  redux.js.org